Aiogram2. FSMContext не записываются данные
Подскажите плз пишу бота на аиограм2, немного запустался в state, мне нужно чтобы пользователь ввел данные и стейт обновился и потом данные из стейта я мог отправить в обработчик оплаты, но почему то когда доходит дело до инвойса в переменной стейта(amount_tickets) лежит None( не могу понять что делаю не так.
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor
from aiogram.types.message import ContentType
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

import random
import sqlite3
import logging
import markups as nav

TELEGRAM_TOKEN = ''
API_TOKEN = ''

# Подключаем БД
conn = sqlite3.connect('lottery.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tickets
                  (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                   user_id INTEGER,
                   number TEXT,
                   phone_number TEXT UNIQUE)''')
conn.commit()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


class AmountTickets(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_tickets = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(AmountTickets.waiting_for_tickets)
    await message.answer('Введите количество билетов"',
                         reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)


@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        await state.update_data(amount_tickets=int(message.text))
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Описание розыгрыша',
                               reply_markup=nav.sub_inline_markup)
    if message.text == 'Количество участников':
        cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets')
        total_users = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Количество участников розыгрыша: {total_users}',
                               reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='ticket')
async def ticket(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.delete_message(call.from_user.id, call.message.message_id)
    data = await state.get_data()
    amount_tickets = data.get('amount_tickets')
    print(amount_tickets)
    await bot.send_invoice(
        chat_id=call.from_user.id,
        title='Покупка билета',
        description='описание',
        payload='ticket_giveaway',
        provider_token=API_TOKEN,
        currency='RUB',
        start_parameter='test_bot',
        need_phone_number=True,
        prices=[{
            'label': 'Привет',
            'amount': (amount_tickets) * 34900
        }]
    )


@dp.pre_checkout_query_handler()
async def process_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query:
                                     types.PreCheckoutQuery):
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query.id, ok=True)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=[ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT,])
async def process_pay(message: types.Message):
    if message.successful_payment.invoice_payload == 'ticket_giveaway':
        ticket_number = random.randint(1000, 9999)
        phone_num = message.successful_payment.order_info.phone_number
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tickets (user_id, number, phone_number) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
                       (message.from_user.id, ticket_number, phone_num))
        conn.commit()
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Вы купили билет номер {ticket_number}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)

